# Hatcher exercise: 2.1.1

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cw-complexes, simplicial-complex

I have already seen an answer to this question, which both places I have found it, it was done pictorially, something I consider useless due to a lack of scalability.(How to learn to deal with problems in the scaling where such pictures fail if you use all the easy examples up by pictures?) I would like to check a few notions of mine:

> The question: Consider $[v_0,v_1,v_2]$ a two dimensional simplicial complex and identify $[v_0,v_1]\sim [v_1,v_2]$ preserving orientation.

It seems then we are also identifying $v_0\sim v_1,v_1\sim v_2$ and so have that $\Delta_0(X)=\langle [v_0]\rangle$ and $\Delta_1(X)=\langle [v_0,v_1],[v_0,v_2]\rangle$, so two loops on $v_0$ (since $v_0\sim v_1\sim v_2$), and $\Delta_2(X)=\langle L\rangle$ where $L$ is the $2$-cell. How do I find the boundary of $L$? $L$ seems to be broken up into two components (disconnected) and has boundary $\langle a,b\rangle$ since I can take a cycle around either independently. Is that correct? Although then with the $2$-cell I can retract this to a point?

Secondly if $\Delta_0(X)\cong \Bbb Z$ as above, this means $H_0(X)=\Bbb Z$, but by having two path components it should be $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$? Or because of the $2$-cell I have 1 path component, rather than the two from Van Kampen?

Comment: Why do you say $L$ is broken into two components?

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought that since $L$ is a $2$-cell it is attached on strictly the 'interior' of these cycles, such that $v_0$ is not contained in $L$, but I will check the definition now.

Comment: I might need to read this more carefully. It seems we do construct the cell complex by taking the $1$ dimensional cell complex and gluing the boundary of a disk to the $1$-cells and the interior itself is considered the $2$-cell, wouldn't that make the 2-cell $L$ disconnected? (Should the $1$-cell complex look like two circles joined at a point?)

Comment: No.  The $2$-cell $L$ isn't "split across" the two loops that its boundary is mapped to.  It's still a $2$-cell (i.e., the interior of a disk); it's just that its boundary circle has gotten glued together in strange ways.